# Accounting Program Loses Connection to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have an accounting system that uses SQL Server 2012 and every now and then we lose connection to the SQL Server and can not access our accounting system. On the surface there appears to be no reason for this (obviously there is).

We have checked the usual culprits like is the SQL Service running (yes it is), are we using a static ip address vs a dynamic ip connection. We are using a static connection and the firewall settings all check out.

So in reviewing the SQL Error Logs we noticed entries in there like the following:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\ReportServer'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: fe80::e504:e492:944e:d309%16]

> The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state. The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

> I/O is frozen on database model. No user action is required. However, if I/O is not resumed promptly, you could cancel the backup.

Since we are not SQL experts would the above error messages be considered the culprit? We are making the assumption they are, but thought we would post here. Unfortunately not exactly sure what these mean other than they are not good obviously.

Does this boil down to a "simple" backup problem? Where mid day server backups are taking an unusual amount of time and hence breaking our connection?

Comment: Do you have info on the backups happening at the same time at the problem?

Comment: Two possible reasons as I see. 1. Please check `auto close` is not enabled for the database see [This](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-close-enabled/#:~:text=In%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio,to%20false%20and%20click%20OK.). 2. The backup you are taking is VSS backup, it seems and this is freezing the I/O leading to disruption. Stop this backup and see if you get any relief.